# What does the "%object" and "@object" mean in this inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

Below code is quoted from here [line 453](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/13230747e3376bbaa4e521a7d181a9dfadca3af5/include/toolchain/gcc.h#L453):

```
#define GEN_ABSOLUTE_SYM_KCONFIG(name, value)       \
    __asm__(".globl\t" #name                    \
        "\n\t.equ\t" #name "," #value       \
        "\n\t.type\t" #name ",%object")
```

For something like this:

```
GEN_ABSOLUTE_SYM_KCONFIG(CONFIG_I2C, 1);
```

I think it should expand to:

```
 .globl      CONFIG_I2C
             .equ          CONFIG_I2C,1
             .type         CONFIG_I2C,%object
```

I can understand that the `#name` and `#value` are just [Stringizing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/and-operators-in-c/).

But what does the `%object` mean?

The `object` is not a formal parameter of the `GEN_ABSOLUTE_SYM_KCONFIG` macro.

Why is it here? And what does the `%` mean? It seems to be arm specific.

And in [line 465](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/13230747e3376bbaa4e521a7d181a9dfadca3af5/include/toolchain/gcc.h#L465), the `%object` changes to `@object` for x86.

```
#define GEN_ABSOLUTE_SYM_KCONFIG(name, value)       \
    __asm__(".globl\t" #name                    \
        "\n\t.equ\t" #name "," #value       \
        "\n\t.type\t" #name ",@object")
```

Comment: Ah, I guess I found some clue: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Type.html#Type

Comment: Yup, just ELF metadata, maybe needed for dynamic linking, otherwise just informative for debuggers.  (At least for most use-cases of stuff like `.type` for functions, IDK about this specifically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"%object"" is a GAS assembler directive specifying a symbol "type":

From the Binutils documentation:

> https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Type.html
>
> For ELF targets, the .type directive is used like this:
>
> .type name , type description This sets the type of symbol name to be
> either a function symbol or an object symbol.

More generally:

> https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/useful-assembler-directives-and-macros-for-the-gnu-assembler
>
> The .type directive allows you to tell the assembler what type a
> symbol is. Most of the time we just use %function and %object.

Comment: `%object` means a data object.